# CDC and object transformation

Tags: debezium, cdc

I have been trying to read about CDC and see how I can use it in my applications. So I have four order booking systems, that store order and order items in their internal database. The tables and columns representing the order and order item in these systems are very different from one another.

I want to build a unified data store of all the orders from the order booking system so that I can make them available for querying by various downstream system and also store them for analytics and ML requirements. All those users who need order information need to only interact with this unified order data store. All the orders from the order booking system will converge to a common order data model in the data store.

Lets say a order item was modified , an entry was created in binlog and a tool like debezium is able to read the binlog for this change. So it has only the row for the changed order item. But I need to build a complete order object as this represents a new state of the order post the update of order item.  Where would one build this complete order and then I would like to publish this as an order event to a kafka topic and have it persisted to a time series DB or a temporal RDBMS.

Can you guide me on where the complete order object should be built, does a tool like debezium let you pull date of the parent tables and help build a complete order object?